# Brew Flooring Systems

Tags: cleaning

I had a few friends use Brewfloors.com flooring systems and they were pretty happy with the results. I'm considering Brewfloors or something else. Do you have other recommendations? If so why?

Thanks guys- Cheers

Comment: Perhaps tell us why you are considering a flooring system? Do you need to change yours anyway or do you want to improve something?

Comment: it looks like its just an epoxy flooring, go with one that meets your needs....

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I'd go with epoxy as well, the sky is the limit.  I wouldn't include a toilet in my brew room if I had a choice tho.